# What's the best way of structuring hiearchy of views in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently converting a ASP.NET webforms solution to MVC.

In webforms we besides the site.master we have master pages where we keep the common code and head imports for each section. So a normal page inheritance goes like so:

```
Site.master -> section.Master -> page.aspx
```

In MVC I'm unclear as to where to place the code common to a section. Is splitting the section content into partial views the only solution? So it becomes?

```
Layout.cshtml -> page.cshtml -> any-number-of-partial-views
```

To give an example, if I need a single CSS file to be shared across all 10 section pages, I can put it in a partial view and render it on each page but doesn't feel incredibly efficient. Or maybe I just need to get my head around to this new way of working.

Comment: Look up for example RenderSections and you can use partial views in your layout as well.

Comment: Reference to all the CSS files which are shared across views should be mentioned in header tag present in _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor) in MVC as well.

In your `_Layout.cshtml` you might have something like this:

```
 @RenderSection("testSection",required:false)
```

And in your child view you can specify what HTML should be rendered in this section or you can leave it all together because `required` has been set to false:

```
@section testSection{

    <h1>Test</h1>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial view is your big friend if you would like to reuse the code several places.

You can put partial view inside Views > ControllerNameAsFolderName > view pages (put here) to use only in same controller views or even inside Shared folder to use globally.

`section` is another option, this is like `UserControl` (in web forms). create section reference `@RenderSection("sectionName", required:false)` on Layout page and use it on view pages like

```
@section sectionName{
    <div>content goes here</div>
}
```

Assume you want to put something (like meta infos) inside `<head>` from view pages, in this case you can create a `section` in `_Layout.cshtml` page and then use that `section` on view pages.

This way you can place your code at certain location in DOM structure from any page. `section` has a great feature that allow you to mark it as `required:false/true`.